# XML Query showing blank results

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Hi I need some help with Querying XML Data in SSMS 2012

I have read various stackoverflow questions and answers as well as follow them.

My Query:

```
DECLARE @x xml
SELECT @x=R

FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\results.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS Results(R)
DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT , @x , '<root xmlns="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:DMF="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08" />'
SELECT * FROM OPENXML (@hdoc,'PolicyEvaluationResults/model/xs:bufferSchema/difinitions/document/data/xs:schema/DMF:bufferData/instances/document/data/DMF:EvaluationHistory',1)

WITH(PolicyName varchar(100))
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

It shows empty results after executing it

I'm trying to get info from the following XML document snippet:

```
<PolicyEvaluationResults>
  <model xmlns="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02">
    <identity>
      <name>urn:uuid:96fe1236-abf6-4a57-b54d-e9baab394fd1</name>
      <baseURI>http://documentcollection/</baseURI>
    </identity>
    <xs:bufferSchema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <definitions xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
         <document>
           <docinfo>
            <aliases>
              <alias>/system/schema/DMF</alias>
            </aliases>
            <sfc:version DomainVersion="3" />
          </docinfo>
          <data>
            <xs:schema xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08" elementFormDefault="qualified">
              <xs:element name="EvaluationHistory">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ConnectionEvaluationHistory">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
               <xs:element name="EvaluationDetail">
                <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:any namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <DMF:bufferData xmlns:DMF="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08">
            <instances xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
              <document>
                <docinfo>
                  <aliases>
                    <alias>/PolicyStore/Policy/Must Change Enabled/EvaluationHistory/1</alias>
                  </aliases>
                  <sfc:version DomainVersion="3" />
                </docinfo>
                <data>
                  <DMF:EvaluationHistory xmlns:DMF="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <DMF:Parent>
                      <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                        <sml:Uri>/PolicyStore/Policy/Must Change Enabled</sml:Uri>
                      </sfc:Reference>
                    </DMF:Parent>
                    <DMF:ConnectionEvaluationHistories>
                      <sfc:Collection>
                        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
                          <sml:Uri>/PolicyStore/Policy/Must Change Enabled/EvaluationHistory/1/ConnectionEvaluationHistory/1</sml:Uri>
                        </sfc:Reference>
                      </sfc:Collection>
                    </DMF:ConnectionEvaluationHistories>
                    <DMF:PolicyName type="string">Must Change Enabled</DMF:PolicyName>
                    <DMF:StartDate type="dateTime">2017-11-28T14:09:50.1639672+02:00</DMF:StartDate>
                    <DMF:EndDate type="dateTime">2017-11-28T14:09:50.4139672+02:00</DMF:EndDate>
                    <DMF:Exception type="string" />
                    <DMF:ID type="long">1</DMF:ID>
                    <DMF:Result type="boolean">false</DMF:Result>
                  </DMF:EvaluationHistory>
```

I have tried different ways to get the results for the PolicyName, StartDate,  ID and Results from the XML Document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the XPath that you are looking for is this:

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT , @xml , 
'<x:model xmlns:x="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" 
          xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" 
          xmlns:DMF="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08" />'

SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc,'/PolicyEvaluationResults/x:model/xs:bufferSchema/x:definitions/
                     x:document/x:data/xs:schema/DMF:bufferData/x:instances/
                     x:document/x:data/DMF:EvaluationHistory',1)
WITH
(
  PolicyName varchar(100) 'DMF:PolicyName'
)
```

[With a SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/14387)

**And the notes:**

- I would suggest you also alias the default xmlns (I've used `x`) for easier traceability.
- I switched to OpenXml in order to use SqlFiddle.
- Typo with the element `definitions`
- `model` itself is in a namespace `xmlns="http://schemas.serviceml.org/smlif/2007/02"`
- Everthing else is in the same namespace as 'model' (which I've namespace aliased to 'x')
- The final element data is also in a namespace. You can specify this after the type definition, e.g. `DMF:PolicyName`

However, that said, you should look to switch to using [XQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22818746/314291) for querying Xml Data in Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

Try it like this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/DMF/2007/08' AS DMF)
SELECT @x.value(N'(//DMF:PolicyName/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS PolicyName
      ,@x.value(N'(//DMF:StartDate/text())[1]',N'datetime') AS StartDate
      ,@x.value(N'(//DMF:ID/text())[1]',N'int') AS ID
      ,@x.value(N'(//DMF:Result/text())[1]',N'bit') AS Result
```

Some explanation: First I declare the only namespace needed: "DMF". In the `XQuery` method `.value()` you state the `XPath` and the `type`. The double slash `//` triggers a deep search, meaning: *Find the first element named "DMF:PolicyName"* without bothering about all the mess around.

I must admit, your XML is very - uhm - complicated... Before I understood the structure I had to repair it by adding closing tags in various places.

The general rule is: Be as specific as possible. In your case the deep nesting and the various namespaces make it very hard to go the clean way, just to get some easy values...