# Extracting Text Values from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, ssms

I'm working with SQL data hosted by a 3rd party, and am trying to pull some specific information for reporting. However, some of what I need to parse out is in XML format, and I'm getting stuck. I'm looking for the syntax to pull the text= values only from the XML code.

I believe the code should something like this, but most of the examples I can find online involve simpler XML hierarchy's than what I'm dealing with.

```
<[columnnameXML].value('(/RelatedValueListBO/Items/RelatedValueListBOItem/text())[1]','varchar(max)')>
```

Fails to pull any results. I've tried declaring the spacenames as well, but again...I only ever end up with NULL values pulled.

Example XML I'm dealing with:

```
<RelatedValueListBO xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/RelatedValueListBOSchema.xsd">
    <Items>
        <RelatedValueListBOItem groupKey="Response1" text="Response1" selected="true" />
        <RelatedValueListBOItem groupKey="Response2" text="Response2" selected="true" />
        <RelatedValueListBOItem groupKey="Response3" text="Response3" selected="true" />
    </Items>
</RelatedValueListBO>
```

Ideally I'd like to pull response1; response2; response3 into a single column.  Allowing for the fact that multiple responses may exist. I believe I'm getting stuck with the basic code I've been trying due to the namespaces associated to RelatedValueListBO and the fact that what I want is grouped in groupKey, text, and selected, instead of the value I want just being under the Items node.

Comment: You should post the actual query you are using. To me it looks like most likely issue is that you did not account for xml namespaces when writing the query.

Comment: Better to do in a real programming language like c#.

Comment: I assume you are using SQL Server, please update tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the namespaces defined in your XML, so you need to define them in the XQuery too.
Fast and dirty method is to replace all namespaces with a "*":

```
SELECT @x.value('(/*:RelatedValueListBO/*:Items/*:RelatedValueListBOItem/@text)[1]','varchar(max)')
```

To get all responses in a single column you can use:

```
SELECT 
 Item.Col.value('./@text','varchar(max)') X
FROM @x.nodes('/*:RelatedValueListBO/*:Items/*:RelatedValueListBOItem') AS Item(Col)
```

If you need a better performance, you may need to define namespaces properly.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Your first response was something I had tried following the 2nd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818591/sql-server-xml-query-with-multiple-namespaces , but I was missing the bloody @ symbol for the text.  Your first answer works fine, and changing the 1 to a 2 etc...pulls subsequent responses I can CONCAT together if needed.  Now I wasn't quite following your 2nd solution, but I did have success with this:

Comment: Columnname = STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), review.value('@text', 'varchar(max)'))
    FROM tablenamea w
        CROSS APPLY w.[ContributingBiologicalFactorsXML].nodes('/*:RelatedValueListBO/*:Items/*:RelatedValueListBOItem') Reviews (Review)
    where w.uniqueid = tablenamea(x).uniqueid
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to extract the value of "text" in the first node of RelatedValueListBOItem

```
SELECT  extractvalue(value(rs), '//RelatedValueListBOItem[1]/@text')
  FROM TABLE (xmlsequence(extract(sys.xmltype('<RelatedValueListBO>
      <Items>
        <RelatedValueListBOItem groupKey="Response1" text="Response1" 
    selected="true" />
    <RelatedValueListBOItem groupKey="Response2" text="Response2" 
    selected="true" />
    <RelatedValueListBOItem groupKey="Response3" text="Response3" 
    selected="true" />
     </Items>
    </RelatedValueListBO>'),'/RelatedValueListBO/Items'))) rs;
```