# Parse XML with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to parse XML in T-SQL but doesn't understand how to write my code.

My XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="https://api.quinyx.com/soap/FlexForce">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:wsdlGetTimePunchesResponse xmlns:ns1="uri:FlexForce">
      <return xsi:type="tns:GetTimePunchesResponse">
        <timepunches xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:TimePunch[1868]">
          <item xsi:type="tns:TimePunch">
            <id xsi:type="xsd:int">134054629</id>
            <employeeName xsi:type="xsd:string">Test, Person</employeeName>
            <restId xsi:type="xsd:int">1111</restId>
            <badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">5000</badgeNo>
            <socsecNo xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <cardNo xsi:type="xsd:string">5000</cardNo>
            <punchIn xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-01-14T08:00:00+01:00</punchIn>
            <punchOut xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-01-14T17:00:00+01:00</punchOut>
            <hours xsi:type="xsd:decimal">8</hours>
            <approvedByEmployee xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</approvedByEmployee>
            <approvedByManager xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</approvedByManager>
            <approvedByCustomer xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</approvedByCustomer>
            <costCentre xsi:type="xsd:string">8002</costCentre>
            <projectNo xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <accountNo xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <agrmntAdditionalField1 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <agrmntAdditionalField2 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <agrmntAdditionalField3 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <agrmntAdditionalField4 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <agrmntAdditionalField5 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <externalInfo1 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <externalInfo2 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <externalInfo3 xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <scheduleId xsi:type="xsd:int">2000000</scheduleId>
            <transferredToPayroll xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</transferredToPayroll>
            <deleted xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</deleted>
            <productiveTime xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</productiveTime>
            <isOpen xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</isOpen>
            <comment xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <managerComment xsi:type="xsd:string" />
            <employeeId xsi:type="xsd:int">1000000</employeeId>
            <ts xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-09-07T09:17:48+02:00</ts>
          </item>
        </timepunches>
        <validationErrors xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]" />
      </return>
```

The XML is stored into a single column in my database table.

I have tried multiple ways to get any data out but they all end up showing nothing.

Doesn't even know where to start to be honest.

It's a SQL Server database.

Here is the existing query:

```
select cast( replace(XMLData, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','') as xml) as XMLData into #temp from [Quniyx].[xmltest] select XMLData.value('return[1]/TimePunch[1]/item[1]/id[1]','int') from #temp
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy - can you show us the SQL Query that you are using to try retrieving this content?

Comment: Hey, 
An example: 

select 
cast(
replace(XMLData, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>','') as xml) as XMLData
into #temp
from [Quniyx].[xmltest]

select 
XMLData.value('return[1]/TimePunch[1]/item[1]/id[1]','int')
from #temp

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818591/sql-server-xml-query-with-multiple-namespaces

Answer (score 1):

The provided XML is not well-formed. I had to adjust it. Additionally, the XML has multiple namespaces. The rest is trivial.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                   xmlns:tns="https://api.quinyx.com/soap/FlexForce">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:wsdlGetTimePunchesResponse xmlns:ns1="uri:FlexForce">
            <return xsi:type="tns:GetTimePunchesResponse">
                <timepunches xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:TimePunch[1868]">
                    <item xsi:type="tns:TimePunch">
                        <id xsi:type="xsd:int">134054629</id>
                        <employeeName xsi:type="xsd:string">Test, Person</employeeName>
                        <restId xsi:type="xsd:int">1111</restId>
                        <badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">5000</badgeNo>
                        <socsecNo xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <cardNo xsi:type="xsd:string">5000</cardNo>
                        <punchIn xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-01-14T08:00:00+01:00</punchIn>
                        <punchOut xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-01-14T17:00:00+01:00</punchOut>
                        <hours xsi:type="xsd:decimal">8</hours>
                        <approvedByEmployee xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</approvedByEmployee>
                        <approvedByManager xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</approvedByManager>
                        <approvedByCustomer xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</approvedByCustomer>
                        <costCentre xsi:type="xsd:string">8002</costCentre>
                        <projectNo xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <accountNo xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <agrmntAdditionalField1 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <agrmntAdditionalField2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <agrmntAdditionalField3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <agrmntAdditionalField4 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <agrmntAdditionalField5 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <externalInfo1 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <externalInfo2 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <externalInfo3 xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <scheduleId xsi:type="xsd:int">2000000</scheduleId>
                        <transferredToPayroll xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</transferredToPayroll>
                        <deleted xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</deleted>
                        <productiveTime xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</productiveTime>
                        <isOpen xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</isOpen>
                        <comment xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <managerComment xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
                        <employeeId xsi:type="xsd:int">1000000</employeeId>
                        <ts xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2019-09-07T09:17:48+02:00</ts>
                    </item>
                </timepunches>
                <validationErrors xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
            </return>
        </ns1:wsdlGetTimePunchesResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri:FlexForce' as ns1, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS [SOAP-ENV])
SELECT ID
    , col.value('(id/text())[1]','INT') AS id
    , col.value('(employeeName/text())[1]','VARCHAR(200)') AS employeeName
    , col.value('(restId/text())[1]','VARCHAR(200)') AS restId
    -- add the rest of the elements here
FROM @tbl tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.xml_data.nodes('/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:wsdlGetTimePunchesResponse/return/timepunches/item') AS tab(col)
```

> Output

```
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+
| ID |    id     | employeeName | restId |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+
|  1 | 134054629 | Test, Person |   1111 |
+----+-----------+--------------+--------+
```